# How to check whether/which matplotlibrc was used

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython

I am using python in an anaconda environment. When I import matplotlib I am getting compatibility issues with xwpython. So, I would like to switch the backend. Usually, that would be done with a matplotlibrc file. However, it seems that matplotlibrc under `~/.config/matplotlib/` is ignored. Is it possible to check whether and which matplotlibrc file was used during import of matplotlib? Using python 2.7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the file path using:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
```

Which in my case returns:

> '/Users/m300241/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc'